# Objective-C How Can I Fix the Back Camera (Camera Facing You) Mirroring The Video?

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation

When I recorded a video with the back camera (camera facing you) using avfoundation, it mirrors the video horizontally and I don't know why. How can I fix this? Really need help!

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the front camera? It's the one facing the user, as it's on the *front* of the device.

Comment: yeah i mean front camera

Answer (score 2):

It has to be the front camera, not the back one. And you can mirror it back by using CALayer property of `playerLayer` in your AVPlayer while playing. Just flip the playerLayer horizontally using `CATransform3DMakeScale`.

```
CATransform3DMakeScale(-1, 1, 1)
```

**UPDATE**:

```
CATransform3D tranform = CATransform3DIdentity;
tranform = CATransform3DScale(tranform, -1, 1, 1);
playerLayer.transform = tranform;
```

If you want to rotate the original video itself then you got to use `AVMutableComposition` and apply instructions according to your need using `AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`. You need to rotate video frame by frame and compose it using `AVMutableComposition`.

Its a bit complex but you can look at the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243847/avfoundation-avplayer-rotation) and use it. Code is about rotating the video to any angle. Use it to rotate by -180 degrees in your case.

Comment: It didnt work. I did playerLayer.transform = CATransform3dMakeScale(-1, 1, 1); ... but it didnt do anything

Comment: @Adp Then make sure your playerLayer is initialised properly and use the code in my edited answer to transform.

Comment: How do I know if it's initialized correctly Cuz I'm pretty sure it is

Comment: Then did my transformation code worked which mentioned in edited answer? It always works for me using transform only. So if still it doesn't work then you have to post your code of AVPlayer for further help.

Comment: the thing is, i dont wanna just flip the avplayer, I want to flip the actual video...because the user has the ability to save the video too...

Comment: Thanks.. Works perfect!