# changing AVPlayer orientation

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I need change my `AVPlayer` orientation when device orientation is changed.
I set `_playerLayer.frame = perentView.bounds` but it doesn't help.

```
_playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_videoPlayer];
_playerLayer.frame = perentView.bounds;
_playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[perentView.layer insertSublayer:_playerLayer atIndex:0];
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243847/avfoundation-avplayer-rotation

Comment: Do you mean that you just want to handle the orientation change and resize the view?  if so I've used constraints from the AVPlayer's AVPlaybackView to it's superview a number of times.  Works fine w/o code.  Link the edges of the AVPlaybackView to the superview and also add the same height/width constraints.