# How to change video orientation of AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, avfoundation, orientation

I want to rotate the replay of a video using AVPlayer. Is there a way to rotate it 90 degrees clockwise?
Here's some code:

```
self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath))
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: self.player)
playerLayer.frame = view.bounds

playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

> UPDATE

This one works:

```
self.player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath))
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: self.player)                                     
playerLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
playerLayer.frame = view.bounds        
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243847/avfoundation-avplayer-rotation

Comment: that's objective c and I've absolutley no experience with that

Comment: it not working code !!

Answer (score 8):

Hooni answer in Swift 3 :

```
let affineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreeToRadian(90))
avPlayerLayer.setAffineTransform(affineTransform)

func degreeToRadian(_ x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return .pi * x / 180.0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Objective-C, the code below will help.

## Sample code:

```
#define degreeToRadian(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
#define radianToDegree(x) (180.0 * x / M_PI)

- (void)rotateVideoPlayerWithDegree:(CGFloat)degree {
    [_playerLayer setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreeToRadian(degree))];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I do,

```
+ (Class)layerClass
{
    return [AVPlayerLayer class];
}
```

Then in init, the class is an NSView:

```
[(AVPlayerLayer*)self.layer setPlayer:player];

self.wantsLayer=YES;
self.superview.wantsLayer=YES;

if (fakePortrait) {
   [self rotateByAngle:90];
}
```

However, this only works in 10.13. I'm looking for a solution for 10.9 and above. If I rotate the video pre 10.13, it disappears.