# Swift - AVFoundations Rotate Video without Exporting It

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset

I have a user upload video that I will then play. The problem is it's sometimes not oriented properly. I looked at solutions to orient the video by exporting it but that is incredibly expensive even with minimal changes.

Is there a way I can change the video without exporting it, the preferred transform is a get-only property.

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to give us more info. Please share a code snippet and explain the source of the video and how you're presenting it. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change video orientation of AVPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736273/how-to-change-video-orientation-of-avplayer)

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts I'm using an AVPlayerViewController, as I need the time controls that come with it. So if I change it then the controls, as well as the video, gets rotated. For example, the play and pause button would be horizontal instead of in its normal position and I only want to change the video orientation

Comment: So from information you posted, how do you suppose people will figure out what you are using, what your problems are and where you need to get? Invest into posting a proper question with the code we can try to reproduce the problem you have. Otherwise this question is unanswerable